# OData v4 using Owin and WebApi works locally but not in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am using the following packages (excerpt):

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Versioning" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

I use the following configuration code (also an excerpt):

```cs
IEnumerable<ODataMediaTypeFormatter> formatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create();
httpConfiguration.Formatters.InsertRange(0, formatters);
httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
httpConfiguration.MapODataServiceRoute("OData", "v1.0", modelBuilder.GetEdmModels().First());

app.UseWebApi(httpServer);
```

Note that I disabled the versioned API part as I thought that may be the cause but as it turned out, it wasn't. The error is still the same. Generally, for all my configuration I use

```cs
HttpServer httpServer = GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer;
HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = httpServer.Configuration;
```

I always use the same `httpConfiguration` variable. No matter which URL I invoke, may it be a simple GET on a set or an OData action locally (IIS) everything works just fine. I remember I had some trouble with the formatters in the beginning but with the current version all is fine locally.

After uploading the code to Azure into a staging environment all OData related requests stop working. Here is a trace:

```
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Type='HttpError', formatters=[MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatterTracer, FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatterTracer]', Operation=PerRequestContentNegotiator.Negotiate
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use same 'FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json'', Operation=JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use same 'JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter' formatter', Operation=JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Type='HttpError', formatters=[MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, MediaTypeFormatterTracer, FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatterTracer, FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatterTracer]', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Obtaining formatter of type 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Will use same 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Selected formatter='ODataMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Selected formatter='ODataMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=PerRequestContentNegotiator.Negotiate
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Information [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Value='System.Web.Http.HttpError', type='HttpError', content-type='application/json; odata.metadata=minimal'', Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
2018-04-24T13:39:30  PID[7936] Error       [2018-04-24T13:39:30.3614885Z] Level=Error, Kind=End, Category='System.Net.Http.Formatting', Id=800002ee-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync, Exception=System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at System.Web.HttpContextBase.get_Response()
   at System.Web.UI.Util.GetUrlWithApplicationPath(HttpContextBase context, String url)
   at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.NormalizeVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, String name, RouteValueDictionary values)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(HttpRequestMessage request, String name, IDictionary`2 values)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper.GetVirtualPath(HttpRequestMessage request, String routeName, IDictionary`2 routeValues)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper.Link(String routeName, IDictionary`2 routeValues)
   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetDefaultBaseAddress(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)
   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__19.MoveNext()
```

It seems like it wants to serialize a `HttpError` object but it cant. I have no clue what is in that error object as I cannot see that. My code does not create such an object. I know that validation does but I do not validate anything yet.

Even a call to `$metadata` will cause this error. The service returns 500 on each request. I can guarantee that my database connection is working fine. I can even see this in the debugger. My controller and the corresponding Action gets invoked (ODataParameters is `null` which it shouldnt) which may also correlate with this.

I did set the .Net Version to 4.7 in the cloud environment. I also tried different settings all day long but nothing made a difference.

My guess is that something is wrong with the whole `HttpConfiguration` stuff.

Has anyone experienced this or does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

downgrade to .net 4.6.1 and may add this node to web config file

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" /> 
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem. It was trivial. I don't know why but `app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration)` killed it. I looked at the stack trace and saw that at some point within WebApi it tried to get a `HttpContext` from a `HttpRequestMessage` which was `null`. So the ultimate solution was to remove this call entirely.

I found this because I desperately recreated the whole project and copied line by line over :(

Thank you @NinjaDeveloper for your answer. I tried it but it didnt change anything. I also tried various other combinations.